# Passing world as parameter results nullpointer

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to create new enemies from their own class. I try to pass World from another class as parameter however when trying to add new body to world it results a nullpointer. Here's the constructor from Enemy-class

```
public Enemy(float x, float y, World world){
    enemyTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.bmp"));
    BodyDef myBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    myBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    myBodyDef.position.set(x, y);

    FixtureDef enemyFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    enemyFixtureDef.density     = 1.5f;
    enemyFixtureDef.restitution = 0.1f;
    enemyFixtureDef.friction    = 0.5f;

    CircleShape circleshape = new CircleShape();
    circleshape.setRadius(enemyRadius);

    enemyFixtureDef.shape = circleshape;
    enemyBody = world.createBody(myBodyDef);
    enemyBody.setUserData("enemy");
    enemyBody.createFixture(enemyFixtureDef);
}
```

Comment: On which line is the null pointer exception thrown?

Comment: When trying to access world. In this case the line with
enemyBody = world.createBody(myBodyDef);

Comment: could you show the code where the Enemy is cretaed to be sure that world object is not null ?

Comment: did you declare `enemyBody` at some point? something like `EnemyBodyClass enemyBody = new EnemyBodyClass(parameters)`?

Comment: enemyBody was declared earlier in that class. However in my main class I tried to add enemy to world before it was created! Feel rather stupid having fought with this over a couple of days. Thanks guys!